# Override Extra Properties in applied script in gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a parent gradle script with some common configuration, but I need to override some values. For this values I define extra properties. Next, in a project I apply the parent file, but I'm not able to override the the value. Here is what I try to do, but id doesn't work.

**Parent gradle script (parent.gradle)**

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

ext {
    artifact = "test"
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: 'someUrl') {
            authentication(userName: 'username', password: 'password')
        }

        pom.project {
            artifactId artifact
        }
    }
}
```

**Project gradle script (build.gradle)**

```
apply from: 'parent.gradle'

ext {
    artifact = "parent-gradle"
}
...
```

In the [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#extraProperties) I did not find any reference on how to do this.

Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Since `parent.gradle` sets the property on its own, there is no way to override the property in such a way that `parent.gradle` will see a different value. What you could do is to not set the property in `parent.gradle` and set it in the other script *before* the `apply from:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Peter. Moving the `ext` statement before `apply` in the `build.gradle`, and removing it from `parent.gradle` solved my problem.